# how to install Phabricator on windows?

Tags: php, phabricator

I tried to install Phabricator on windows 8 with WAMP Apache Server.

As per the below link I installed Arcanist and confirmed with the comment

```
arc -v
```

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_windows/

Next I try to access the Phabricator page on my localhost, I can see only the .sh for Linux, Nothing for windows. Please guide me if you installed successfully on windows.

```
http://localhost/phabricator/scripts/install/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below steps to setup phabricator/arc cli on windows box.

1. Download & Install Git Bash.
2. It needs PHP, if you don't have PHP installed on machine then you use XAMP or WAMP. Find the installation directory for PHP and set system path for that.
3. Open command prompt and test the php installation by writing php command. If it does not show any error then you can skip step-4.
4. In case of MSVCR100.dll missing error. download the exe file from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679 and install it.Once again test php installation.

Use Git Bash to do following:

5. Clone below repos somewhere:

   `git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git`

   `git clone https://github.com/phacility/arcanist.git`
6. Again update system path similar to step 3 and add there : `<path>\arcanist\bin`
7. Test arc help command in Git Bash.
8. Install Phabricator server certificate using `arc install-certificate` command.
9. Add an editor by following https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_windows/

Comment: how to run Phabricator Daemons then?

Comment: @GilangJalu The Daemons seem to just be running PHP scripts.

Comment: Follow-up question would be why are none of the CLI tools (in Phabricator) working when trying to invoke from git bash on Windows?  It'll show the description of the tool, but won't register any options provided to it.

Comment: Nevermind.  Figured out that you have to execute the php file it's linked to from regular command prompt (at least that's what I figured out).  And there will be some growing pains (as I'm currently setting up Phabricator on Windows - and yes, it's working) with trying to setup some lingering libraries that it expects you to natively support.

Comment: Getting error with step 8, asking for api token which generated from https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/login/  . After login i am getting error The external account ("Google") you just authenticated with is not configured to allow registration on this Phabricator install. An administrator may have recently disabled it" I have tried with three different authentications facebook, google and github. Getting the same error.

Comment: so finally at the end of the day we can install Phabricator in windows, contrary to what other answers say?

Comment: OMG, Phabricator would save lives in offices that are bound to stupid Windows, but I have to back down to Redmine because of both Windows and SVN support our team requires :(

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install Phabricator on Windows. However, you can install it on a Virtual Box such as Oracle VM VirtualBox which is free. Once you have VirtualBox, you need to create a Virtual Ubuntu there. After installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox you can install Phabricator there, on Ubuntu, by following the instructions.

If you need more help with details and whatnot, I will gladly help you.

Answer (score 3):

The Phabricator server does not support Windows. See the [Install Guide](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/):

> To install the Phabricator server software, you will need an operating system ... which is not Windows. ... [T]he server software does not run on Windows. It does run on most other operating systems, so choose one of these instead:

Comment: :'( That's so bad I cannot use this beautiful piece of software on our organization's machine with Windows Server... One solution is to run on WSL on my working PC (which I did successfully), but then installed Phabriactor depends on my device's state.